# Detect a collision on bottom of frame

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am going out of my mind trying to detect a collision for the bottom of the ball when it touches the connect1 UIimageview

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, box.frame)) 
{
    yesno.text=@"Found the spot";
}
```

**This obviously detects any part of the frame.

If anyone could point me in the correct direction I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking at the intersection of the ball's frame and the box's frame, look for the intersection of the ball's frame with a rectangle whose top is aligned with the bottom of the box.

```
CGRect bottom = CGRectMake(box.frame.x, box.frame.y + box.frame.height, box.frame.width, 50.0);
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, bottom)) 
{
    yesno.text=@"Found the spot";
}
```

Alternatively, assuming that the ball is normally inside the box, it's probably faster to simply check the position of the ball with respect to the box:

```
CGFloat ballBottom = ball.frame.y + ball.frame.height;
CGFloat boxBottom = box.frame.y + box.frame.height;
if (ballBottom > boxBottom) {
    yesno.text=@"Found the spot";
}
```